# "fit" usage as a transitive verb

Tags: verbs

The Cambridge Dictionary says that `fit` means "to be the right size or shape for someone or something", and gives an example:

> That jacket fits you perfectly.

Since `fit` is used as a transitive verb in this example, should I consider this to mean `that jacket` makes `you` `the right size`?

**EDIT**
Thank you all for your replies.

I've been trying to figure out why I'm confused, and I think it probably stems from the fact that the dictionary definition of "fit" is more like an adjective, and yet it is used as a verb. Moreover, it is used as a transitive verb, without a preposition, and the action subject is not clear. As a non-native speaker, it seems like a pretty special word to me.

Who should we consider the action subject to be in the first place?

Comment: It means **That jacket is the right size For you**.

Comment: If so, why not write "That jacket fits for you" or "fits to you"? Why only "That jacket fits you"?

Comment: Bcoz there is already **for** in the definition.

Comment: Why is "for" included in the definition of "fit" when used in this sense? Since "fit" is also used as an intransitive verb, it doesn't seem bad to write "fit for you".

Comment: How can a jacket make someone the right size? Where do you see causation in the original sentence or the definition you quoted?

Comment: Is the grammar of your native language’s equivalent of “fit” confusing you?

Answer (score 1):

In, "It fits you," *fit* is a verb* that indicates the item fits well on the person, not that it makes the *person* the right size.

However, in similar examples, below, the effect is on the subject:

- The dress *beautifies* her.
- That suit *ages* him.
- The new engine *speeds* the car.

Answer (score 1):

It happens that *fit* is transitive in English (takes a direct object).

This is the kind of thing that varies between languages, and between words in a language, in an unpredictable way.

In English we *listen to* something and we *wait for* something, but in French we *écouter* something or *attendre* something (with a direct object).

Furthermore, in Welsh we *gwrando ar* ("listen on") something and in Irish we *eisteacht le* ("listen with") something. And in English, though we *listen to* something, we *look at* something (not *look to* it, which has a different meaning).